# Encoding and decoding ASN.1 REAL with BER

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, asn.1

Excuse me for my bad english. I have a number in the decimal system: **0.15625**.

(This is example) http://www.strozhevsky.com/free_docs/asn1_in_simple_words.pdf (Page 5)

By the rule of BER ASN.1 - Encoded in octal: **09 03 90 FE 0A** (This is the right decision)

http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf - 
Standart ASN.1(8.5 - REAL)

**1 byte:**

```
(8-7) Class - Universal - 00 
(6) P/C - Primitive - 0
(5-1) Tag Number - 01001(REAL)
```

**TOTAL: 00001001(2) = 09(16)** (Correct)

**2 byte:**

```
     (8) binary encoding - 1
      _____________________
     (7) When binary encoding is used (bit 8 = 1), then if the mantissa M is 
         non-zero, it shall be represented by a sign S, a positive integer value N 
         and a binary scaling factor F, such that:
            M = S × N × 2F
         Bit 7 of the first contents octets shall be 1 if S is –1 and 0 otherwise. 
         What I would have bit 7?
        _____________________
     (6-5) base 8 - 01
       _______________________
     (3-4) Bits 4 to 3 of the first contents octet shall encode the value of
     the binary scaling factor F as an unsigned binary
     integer. I don't have scaling factor. - 00
      _____________________
     (2-1) 8.5.6.4 Bits 2 to 1 of the first contents octet shall encode 
     the format of the exponent as follows: I do not know how to determine 
     what my value will be here. (Poor understand English). I think 11?
```

**Total: 1?010011 - NOT EQUAL 03** Why? (Not correct)

What does the **90**? Call octet? How to find it? The book does not say, or I simply do not understand.

In **FE** coded number -2(Exponent), how do I translate **FE**, not to get 254, and -2? Perhaps it contains information about the byte: **90**?

Thank you for listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the section "Chapter 1. Common rules for ASN.1 encoding" it states that an encoding has three sections:

1. an information block
2. a length block
3. a value block

The length block specifies the length of the value block.

The encoding of 0.15625 as the octets `09 03 80 FB 05` breaks down like this:

```
09       - information block (1 octet)
03       - length block (1 octet)
80 FB 05 - value block (3 octets)
```

The value block itself consists of three sections: an information octet, a block for the exponent and a block for the mantissa. In this case the mantissa is M = 5  (101 in base 2) and the exponent is E = -5. Therefore the value block is:

```
80       - information octet
FB       - the exponent block (FB = -5)
05       - the mantissa block (5)
```

The information octet specifies various pieces of information including:

- that we are encoding a real number
- we are using in base 2, and
- the number is non-negative (>= 0)

To answer your question about FE being interpreted as -2, this is how negative numbers are represented in 2s-complement arithmetic [(more info)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). For single octet numbers we have:

```
FF   ->  -1
FE   ->  -2
FD   ->  -3
...
80   ->  -128
7F   ->  +127
7E   ->  +126
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And whether you have examples of decoding and encoding REAL? Very little information on the Internet, and online coding adds a lot of confusing things for me.

Comment: For example greater than the number that the mantissa and exponent in double digits.